# MySQL Stored Procedure returns 0 in parameters from a SELECT

Tags: mysql

I created a Stored Procedure in MySQL to return some parameters from a SELECT, but doesn't work.

ever returns 0 in userID and otherID.

Someone can help me?
Thanks

> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_XPTO;
>
> DELIMITER ;;
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_XPTO(
>
> OUT userID              INT UNSIGNED,
>
> OUT otherID             INT UNSIGNED,
>
> IN  bookID              INT UNSIGNED
>
> )
>
> BEGIN
>
> SELECT userID=E.userID, otherID=E.otherID
>
> FROM Exp as E
>
> WHERE E.bookID = bookID;
>
> END ;;
>
> DELIMITER ;

---

UPDATED:

Sorry,
After I read a lot, I concluded that the error is in how I call the stored procedure, and Ravinder is correct.
Thanks

Comment: quickly creating a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) helps fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your intention is to check the existence of a value in database.
Because, your `select` statement is doing a *comparison* but not assignment.

```
SELECT userID=E.userID, otherID=E.otherID
```

With the above statement, you may be thinking that value of `E.userID` is assigned to the `OUT` parameter `userID`. But the syntax you used is wrong.

In the above statement, both of the expressions return a `boolean`. As `userID` value did not match with `E.userID` the comparison resulted a `false` and you saw a `0`. And it was the same for the `otherID` variable.

To assign values to variables you have to use `INTO` instructional operator.

**Example**:

```
SELECT E.userID, E.otherID 
  INTO userID,   otherID
```

Change your stored procedure as below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_XPTO;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_XPTO(
   OUT userID INT UNSIGNED,
   OUT otherID INT UNSIGNED,
    IN bookID INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
   SELECT E.userID, E.otherID
     INTO userID,   otherID
   FROM Exp as E
   WHERE E.bookID = bookID;  -- <- there was a ')'. removed.
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Call the procedure with desired parameters and read the out parameters.

```
call sp_XPTO( @userID, @otherID, 234 ); -- where book id is 234
select @userID, @otherID;
```